# How can I access the GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi from Docker container and how to avoid conflicts?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gpio

How can I configure a docker container so I can access and manipulate a pin of the GPIO and how can I avoid a conflict between more than one container, ex. if two Containers try to turn on/off a led, how could be avoided this race situation?